# Create Template Board and Cards on Trello

Tags: trello

Is it possible to create a board as a template? It would be nice to create the board with a pre-defined set of lists and cards for a standard set of tasks.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible to do currently. But it might be possible through the [API](http://trello.com/api)

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible, but there is a (very highly voted) [card for that feature](https://trello.com/c/LIqasVwP).

Until that is implemented, you might consider using the [Trello Clone](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/igdohpdnohikeonpipombhdepnmbigkl?hl=en-US&gl=US) Chrome Extension (written by a third party).

Comment: "card for that feature" link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now, not sure when the feature was released but it's been a while!

There is a guide to some of the FAQs around Trello templates [here](https://www.bluecatreports.com/blog/best-trello-board-examples/#FAQs)